# JPA Predicate With Subselect and GrouBy

Tags: jpa, group-by, tuples, predicate, subquery

I need to use a `CriteriaQuery<Tuple>` in a subquery to get the data I need. What I cannot seem to figure out is how to specify it in my `Predicate`.

For this example, we are wanting to return the most recent population data for every county within a specified state.

Here is the SQL that gives me exactly the result I want:

```
select * from TB_POPULATION
where (COUNTY_ID, EFFECTIVE_DATE) in
      ( select COUNTY_ID, max(EFFECTIVE_DATE) from TB_POPULATION
        where STATE_ID = 47
        group by COUNTY_ID
      )
and STATE_ID = 47
;
```

I have a single `PopulationDataBean` entity at this point:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TB_POPULATION")
public class PopulationDataBean {
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalDate")
    @Column(name = "EFFECTIVE_DATE", nullable = false)
    private LocalDate effectiveDate;
    @Column(name = "STATE_ID", precision = 15, scale = 0, nullable = false)
    private Long stateId;
    @Column(name = "COUNTY_ID", precision = 15, scale = 0, nullable = false)
    private Long countyId;
    @Column(name = "POPULATION", precision = 9, scale = 0, nullable = false)
    private Long popCount;
    ...
}
```

I can create the subquery that returns the `Tuple`, but I cannot figure out how to specify that the subquery result needs to match `PopulationDataBean_.countyId` and `PopulationDataBean_.effectiveDate` in the main where clause.